# Comparing values in a JSON file using Pycharm

Tags: python, json, comparison

New to reading and writing with Python and JSON, so go easy on me, but would appreciate any help!

OK so I am using Pycharm and am reading in a large JSON file with the following code and able to print it out:

```
    import json
    from pprint import pprint
    with open('Files/InstrumentPublished.json') as data_file:
         data = json.load(data_file)
    pprint(data)
```

Within the JSON file I am reading there are 4 fields I want to look at: A_ID, B_ID, C_ID and D_ID.  All these fields should have the same value, ie (they are located in different places throughout the JSON file:

```
     "A_ID": "12345",
      ......
     "B_ID": "12345",
      .......
     "C_ID": "12345",
      ........
     "D_ID": "12345",
```

Basically I need to add the following logic when reading the file:

1. Identify the following fields in the JSON file: A_ID, B_ID, C_ID and D_ID
2. Read/consume their value and compare them
3. If all values are the equal print true.
4. If all values are not equal, print false.

I have searched around the internet but can only find reading and writing to a JSON using Python but nothing of comparing individual fields.

Like I said any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Kirsty

Comment: JSON is a *notation*. What you describe is comparing the *contained data*. You should have more luck looking for how to compare the data instead of the JSON - namely, how to compare fields of a Python ``dict``.

Comment: Yes I agree but need help to get there

Comment: Accessing values in a dictionary and comparing values are pretty basic operations in Python. What part are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: Please see below.  I understand the concept but it is not working below!

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1):

When you read a JSON in Python it becomes a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp), then you can access each key value with the square bracket

Here is the code

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('Files/InstrumentPublished.json') as data_file:
     data = json.load(data_file)
all_ids_equal = data['A_ID'] == data['B_ID'] == data['C_ID'] == data['D_ID']
print(all_ids_equal)
```

Comment: No luck  File "C:/Users/k_meredith/PycharmProjects/TestK01/Testk01.py", line 5, in <module>
    all_ids_equal = data['A_ID'] == data['B_ID'] == data['C_ID'] == data['D_ID']
KeyError: 'A_ID'

Comment: It does have A_ID in the JSOn file but cannot find it, does it need to be read first?

Comment: @KirstyMeredith maybe you to tell us what's the output of `pprint(data)`. Seems like your JSON structure is different than as explained in the question.

Comment: { "A_ID": "12345", "name":"John", "B_ID": "12345", "age":30, "C_ID": "12345", "status":"married","D_ID": "12345"}

Comment: Condensed it but it is not finding 'A_ID' at all -

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers